For $\theta=\frac{p}{q}$ $\xi_n=\langle n\theta\rangle$ is equidistributed on $0$, $\frac{1}{q}$, $\frac{2}{q},\ldots,\frac{q-1}{q}$.
this is exercise 6 chapter 4 of Steins Fourier analysis. I wrote a little proof where I am currently stuck. First my proof attempt:
Let $\theta=\frac{p}{q}$ be a rational number where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime integers. We assume without loss of generality that $q>0$. Define a sequence of numbers in $[0,1)$ by $\xi_n=\langle n\theta\rangle$ where $\langle .\rangle$ denotes the fractional part. Show that the sequence $\{\xi_1,\xi_2,...\}$ is equidistributed on the points of the form $0$, $\frac{1}{q}$, $\frac{2}{q}$,...$\frac{q-1}{q}$. In fact, prove that for any $0\leq a \leq q$, one has
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\#\{n:1\leq n\leq N, \langle n\theta\rangle=\frac{a}{q}\}}{N}=\frac{1}{q}+O\left(\frac{1}{N}\right).
\end{align*}
Solution.
Claim: For each integer $k\geq 0$, there is a unique integer $n$ s.t. $kq\leq n < (k+1)q$.
Please consider, $q\neq 1$ since if that the case, we have $\langle n\theta\rangle =0$ for all $n$. Thus, we have to have $q\geq 2$.
Now suppose there is no integer between $(k+1)q$ and $kq$. Then,
\begin{align*}
    (k+1)q=kq+1\\
    \iff q=1
\end{align*}
a contradiction. (If $k$ is negative, the argumentation just needs to be adjusted by $-1$) In the case $k=0$, we have $q>n\geq 0$, this holds since $q\geq 2$.
By that we can see that $\frac{n}{q}\in [y,y+1)$ and $np=(yq+a)p$, thus $\langle n\theta\rangle=\frac{a'}{q}$, where $a'$ is the rest of $ap|q$.
Next Claim: For $0\leq l$ and $0 \leq r < q$ we have $l\leq \#\{n:1\leq n\leq N, \langle n\theta\rangle=\frac{a}{q}\} \leq l+1$.
First note that we can divide $N$ by $q$ with remainder, that is $N=lq+r$. Now note
\begin{align*}
    N=lq+r
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
      N&>lq\\\\
  \iff  \frac{N}{q}&>l
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
    N=lq+r < lq+q =(l+1)q
\end{align*}
therefore:
\begin{align*}
    l\leq \#\left\{n:1\leq n\leq N, \langle n\theta\rangle=\frac{a}{q}\right\} \leq l+1.
\end{align*}
Lastly,
\begin{align*}
    \frac{l}{N}\leq\frac{\#\{n:1\leq n\leq N, \langle n\theta\rangle=\frac{a}{q}\}}{N} &\leq \frac{l+1}{N}\\\\
    \iff \frac{1}{q}-\frac{r}{N}\leq\frac{\#\{n:1\leq n\leq N, \langle n\theta\rangle=\frac{a}{q}\}}{N} &\leq \frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{N}\\\\
    \Rightarrow \frac{\#\{n:1\leq n\leq N, \langle n\theta\rangle=\frac{a}{q}\}}{N} &= \frac{1}{q}+O\left(\frac{1}{N}\right).
\end{align*}
(Note $\frac{1}{q}-\frac{r}{N}、\leq  \frac{1}{q}-\frac{2r}{Nq}<\frac{l}{N}$ in the case $q\geq 2$. The case $q=1$ results in the trivial case of $\langle n\theta \rangle = 0$ for all $n$.)
The equidistribution follows, since we need that every $q$'th $n$ has to be taken out, since it will not be fractional. Therefore, we have to have:
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{N\to \infty}\frac{N}{N}\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{q}=&=\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{q}+O\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)=
    \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\#\{n:1\leq n\leq N, \langle n\theta\rangle=\frac{a}{q}\}}{N} 
\end{align*}
Now my question, is my conclusion, of the equidistribution at the end correct? (or are there any mistakes in the proof) (since the book only defines equidistribution on intervalls)
Thank you!

TeX note: it will look better if you use \langle and \rangle for the fractional part instead of < and > .

Tip: Better to use \langle and \rangle than < and >. Compare $\langle n \rangle$ to $$.

@GregMartin : Wow, we both were making the same comment at the same time!

Great minds think alike! ;)

Thanks for the advise, I adjusted it =)

Fractional Part notation is $\left{\cdots\right}$ which comes from the $\LaTeX$ code $\verb*\left{\cdots\right}*$

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.
